# Django | Query filter returns more results than it should

Tags: python, django, database, filter

I'm not sure entaily what I've done here but when I try to filter my database I get more results than I should. I'm trying to get a list of episodes that share the same season ID.

[Screen shot of Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5wjk.png)

There is 1 entry with the franchies_item_name_id = 67 which I filter for (Normally I'm getting this from something else but try to solve issue I've just entered the number).

3 entries with franchies_name_id = 2 which I don't care about in this instance.

```py
episodes_query = Episides.objects.filter(franchies_item_name_id=67)
            print(f'tv_item.id {tv_item.id}')
            print(f'episodes_query {episodes_query}')
```

What is I get back is all the items that have franchies_name_id = 2

```
tv_item.id 67
episodes_query <QuerySet [<Episides: Episides object (3)>]>
```

I'm sure I've done something dumb here but not the foggiest what.

It works fine if for franchies_item_name_id = 5

Comment: Well you only get one item back: the one with primary key `3`.

Comment: The `3` is not the number of elements, but just one element, with primary key `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `3` is not the number of elements, but just one element, with primary key `3`. Indeed the standard `repr(…)` for a model is `ModelName object (pk)`. So the `QuerySet` contains *one* elements, and the *primary key* of that element is 3.

If you for example print the length, so the number of elements:

```
print(len(episodes_query))  # 1
```

or if you iterate over it:

```
for item in episodes_query:
    print('item')
```

it will print `item` once.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. In which case I think my issue is something to do with my HTML as I'm getting all 3 results there. Imma have look see if I can work out

Comment: Found it. I was appending the data together later on instead of sending the result to the class to be messed with in a loop.

Thank you very much for the help